# Declaring an array

Tags: php

```
$a[]="Anna";
$a[]="Brittany";
$a[]="Cinderella";
$a[]="Diana";
$a[]="Eva";
$a[]="Fiona";
$a[]="Gunda";
```

When declaring it this way, does it automatically increase the index? Why is this ideal?

Comment: What happens when you run that code and try to access the array?

Comment: It's ideal because it makes adding new elements to the array a breeze! You don't have to deal with incrementing the index.

Comment: you can also do the same thing as: `$a = array('Anna', 'Brittany' ... )`

Comment: It is also useful when populating arrays using loops.. :D

Comment: @webdestroya I would pick your comment as best answer.

Comment: Note that none of these actually "declare" an array, except for the first if you haven't already created `$a` as an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does. It may not be ideal for *you*, but it sure is convenient for most people.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. See the [PHP arrays guide](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Note that if you want to delete the array, you can use:

```
unset($a);
```

Or if you want to make $a become an empty array, you can use:

```
$a = array();
```

Comment: +1 for actually linking to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying). Seriously, people.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.  It may not be 'ideal' - but considering that you're setting an array equal to a single value, adding to the array is better than overwriting the entire array, which I suppose would be the other option for that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It automatically increasing a index but start with '0'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its ideal, because if its not, then use an associative array.